# Unable to size the list element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a custom `width` and `height` to the list element but unable to do so.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="myclass">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color:green;"><span class="myspanclass">0</span></li>
        <li class="liclass" style="background-color:green;">0</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Style :**

Below works :

```
.myclass ul {list-style-type:none; padding: 0px;}
.myclass li {display: inline; margin-right: 10px;}
```

None of the below works :

```
.myclass ul li {width:50px; height:50px;}
.myclass li {width:50px; height:50px;}
.liclass {width:50px; height:50px;}
.myspanclass {width:50px; height:50px;}
```

What am I doing wrong? The `li` has a background color green and it should appear as a `50x50` box as defined in the css style. But its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use  `display: inline-block;` instead of  `display: inline;`

```css
.myclass ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.myclass li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:green;"><span class="myspanclass">0</span></li>
    <li class="liclass" style="background-color:green;">0</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply width or height to items with an inline display. You'll have to use `display: block`.

As others have suggested, `display:inline-block` also works but not for IE6 or IE7.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Check out this.

```
.myclass ul li {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.myclass ul li:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.myclass ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```